# Postgres exception :javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException: Heuristic Exception

Tags: spring, jdbc, jta, spring-transactions

I am creating an application using Spring with PostgreSQL 9.2 on Windows. I am running this application in Windows 32 bit OS successfully. But same application when i am trying to run in Windows 64 bit OS, I get the following exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.HeuristicCompletionException: Heuristic completion: outcome state is mixed; nested exception is javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException: Heuristic Exception
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1016)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:754)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:723)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:393)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:120)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:622)
    at com.kensho.common.UIbundlDAOImpl$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$ca55a3ce.findAll(<generated>)
    at com.kensho.common.UIToolKitAdminBBean.getAllBundleItems(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:346)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:299)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:132)
    ... 38 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException: Heuristic Exception
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.rethrowAsJtaHeuristicMixedException(TransactionImp.java:77)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:238)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.commit(TransactionManagerImp.java:498)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.UserTransactionImp.commit(UserTransactionImp.java:129)
    at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1009)
    ... 53 more
Caused by: com.atomikos.icatch.HeurHazardException: Heuristic Exception
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorStateHandler.rollback(CoordinatorStateHandler.java:802)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.ActiveStateHandler.prepare(ActiveStateHandler.java:223)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.prepare(CoordinatorImp.java:833)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CoordinatorImp.terminate(CoordinatorImp.java:1160)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTerminatorImp.commit(CompositeTerminatorImp.java:92)
    at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:236)
```

....
Why i am getting this problem ?

Comment: That backtrace looks incomplete, but it looks like you're having issues with JTA transaction management. I suspect the 32bit vs 64-bit difference is leading you astray and the real problem is a difference in configuration between the two environments. I'd say you're using an XA transaction to control two or more datasources, and only one of them commits successfully,

Comment: Thanks craig for your reply .What configuration i need to do to make it work in windows 64 bit env.

Comment: By "configuration" I mean your app's setup, I think something is different between your 32-bit and 64-bit setups. I have no possible way of knowing what with the information you have provided. All I can tell you is that it looks like you have an XA transaction where one or more XA datasources aren't able to cleanly all commit together or all rollback together.

Comment: BTW, you haven't even mentioned your JVM version, the container you're running in, the PgJDBC version, which other data sources you're using, or anything else that might help diagnose the issue. No problem code is shown.

Comment: Should i provide JTA props used for better understanding ?

Comment: If you like, but I doubt it'll make any difference. As written this is just way too specific to your app and environment. I've given you some hints about where you might want to look, but I can't debug your application for you. I recommend trying to make a self-contained test case that demonstrates the problem; you'll most likely find the bug in the process of doing so. See http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2):

In conjunction with PostgreSQL 9.x and 10.x this issue has been experienced in conjunction with Seam and Apache JCR and too low values for `max_connection` and `max_prepared_transactions` in the PostgreSQL configuration.